# WebMatrix 3 example website LICENSE

Tags: web, webmatrix

I like so much the template (CSS, HTML, JS and C# code) of the default template of the WebMatrix 3. Somebody know what license has it? I intend use this example for my website and, maybe, license the code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no licence attached to the template design.

Comment: Give me fonts, please :).

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The templates that the WebMatrix template gallery provides you with is FreeWare or ShareWare you can say. You can use it, edit it, share it with others too.

If you want to develop the website of yours using that template. You're allowed to do so. You can edit the templates and create your own website depending on your needs. You can further share it, sell it.

You can even give your own license to the code that you've written to the template if you want to sell it or use for some other function. You're totally allowed to do so.